# Convert anonymous user to registered user with Firebase Auth for Google

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth with VueJS and I need to convert an [anonymous auth user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) to a [registered one with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

I'm using this code from an example:

```
  fromAnonymousToGoogle: function () {
  // Authenticate with the first user then save the currentUser to a local variable
    var previousUser = Firebase.auth().currentUser

  // Authenticate with a second method and get a credential
    var credential = Firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

    previousUser.link(credential)
    .catch(function (error) {
     // Linking will often fail if the account has already been linked. Handle these cases manually.
      alert(error)
    })

    // OAuth providers authenticate in an asynchronous manner, so you’ll want to perform the link account link in the callback.
    // previousUser = Firebase.auth().currentUser;
    Firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new Firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
     .then(function (result) {
       return previousUser.link(result.credential)
     })
     .catch(function (err) {
       // Handle error
       alert(err)
     })
  },
```

I get this error by trying to link the account to Google:

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: this.ta is not a function"

I don't have a function called **this.ta** in my code. How to fix this error?

Comment: Do you have `@click="ta"` somewhere in a template?

Comment: No. I'm using a different naming scheme.

Comment: **My goal is to let an anonymous user change his account to a registered user. Any ideas welcome.**

Comment: Every example on firebase docs has "addScope" method after initialization. Have you tried adding scope?

Comment: @OnurÖzkan They are optional for Google, aren't they? `Optional: Specify additional OAuth 2.0 scopes that you want to request from the authentication provider. To add a scope, call addScope. For example:` Link docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth - This shows you how to do it easily!

Comment: @Freddie The main problem with the examples provided in that guide is that it assumes that you've already obtained the credential for Google and just want to then link them. It appears that Tom is still needing to obtain those credentials. I've outlined an answer that should show how to approach it using the popup method that Tom was using for sign-in with Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer you last question, the reason you're running into this error is because you're not actually getting a credential with `var credential = Firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()` but a Provider ID. So when you're trying to `link()` with the provider ID, it simply isn't working (I verified running into the same error due to this section of your code).

You actually don't want to sign in the user with the Google credentials, since this would sign out your anonymous user and sign in using Google. You just want to link the current user with some Google credentials, which you can just use the `linkWithPopup` method to accomplish (I renamed variables to make a little more sense).

```
fromAnonymousToGoogle: function () {
            // Authenticate with the first user then save the currentUser to a local variable
            var anonUser = Firebase.auth().currentUser

            // Authenticate with a second method and get a credential
            var provider = new Firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

            anonUser.linkWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
                googleToken = result.credential;
                console.log(googleToken);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Google sign in failed", error);
            });
    },
```

Having tested this out myself, this appears to be the way to approach linking them using a [popup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking), most closely matched to your originally provided code.